# How to color an image based on a dynamically changing percentage value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fill

I have an image which i want to fill with some color based on a dynamically changing value that represents percentage, e.g. if the value is 50% half of the image should be colored.

How to achieve that using JavaScript (jQuery can be used)?

Comment: The image should have 50% colour? Or the image should be half-coloured (the left-side coloured, the right side greyscale)?

Comment: In my case its barrel which i want to fill as per the percentage, so if its 50% then its should be bottom half filled, But i would like to know if it can be done otherwise too i.e. from left to right or vice-versa.

Comment: please tick my answer accepted if it solved your issue, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish that by utilizing the `clip` CSS property, and a little bit of added markup to serve an underlaying container for the unrevealing background color.

### Abstract

Place an element underneath the image for the faux color fill, and set its dimensions and position to match the images'. Then use JavaScript to clip the image dynamically - thus revealing the underlying color - by altering the `clip` value of the image element according to your needs (you can, of course, control each offset separately, e.g. left, bottom).

***Note:** To achieve specifically what you desire you can alter the underlying element to contain another image that suits your needs (i.e. a top image of an empty barrel, and a bottom image of a full one).*

### Implementation

In this example a slider is used to trigger the value change.

#### Markup

```html
<input type="range"  min="0" max="100" id="slider" value="100" />
<div id="underlay"></div>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/500/207" id="image" />
```

#### Styles

```css
#slider,
#image,
#underlay {
    /* absolute positioning is mandatory for clipped elements (#image) */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    width: 500px;
}
#image,
#underlay {
    top: 100px;
    height: 207px;
}
#image {
    /* initial clip state */
    clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, 500px);
}
#slider {
    top: 50px;
}
#underlay {
    background-color: #4C76A5;
}
```

#### Functionality

```js
var img = document.getElementById('image');
var sld = document.getElementById('slider');

sld.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

    // get the slider value
    var val = e.srcElement.value;
    // calc the percentage to pass an absolute length value to the clip property
    var perc = img.width / 100 * val;

    // set the images' left offset clip accordingly
    img.style.clip = 'rect(auto, auto, auto, ' + perc + 'px)';
});
```

### Live Demo

- **[On jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/WVeGM/)**

### References

- [`clip` on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clip)
- [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip)